# Split negative number apart and then sum together

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to write a function to sum the individual digits of a negative and positive number. I get stuck on how to sum the negative number after I've split the digits apart. Can I escape the '-' sign to have (-538) return `['-5', '3', '8' ]` instead of `[ '-', '5', '3', '8' ]` or am I going about the wrong way of solving this problem?

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
    var count = 0;
    
    var intermediate =  num.toString().split('')
    
    for(var i = 0; i < intermediate.length; i++){
        count += parseInt(intermediate[i])
        
}
   return count; 
}


var positive = sumDigits(2309);
console.log(positive); // --> 14


var negative = sumDigits(-8525);
console.log(negative); // --> 4
```

Comment: `var intermediate = num.toString().match(/-?[0-9]/g);`

Comment: Your snippet currently has a syntax error in it (the semicolon after `intermediate[i];`)...

Comment: you might want to try modulo operation on the number and sum the remainders.

Comment: Why not just take the absolute value of the number first? `var intermediate =  Math.abs(num).toString().split('')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with regex which matches optional `-` with the digit.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  var count = 0;
  var intermediate = num.toString().match(/-?\d/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < intermediate.length; i++) {
    count += parseInt(intermediate[i])
  }
  return count;
}


var positive = sumDigits(2309);
console.log(positive);


var negative = sumDigits(-8525);
console.log(negative);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `nextIsMinus` to true, in case the current char is a `-`, like so:

```js
function sumDigits(num)
{
    var count = 0;
    var intermediate =  num.toString().split('')
    var nextIsMinus = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < intermediate.length; i++)
    {
        if(intermediate[i] == "-")
        {
            nextIsMinus = true;
        } else
        {
            if(nextIsMinus)
            {
                count -= parseInt(intermediate[i]);
                nextIsMinus = false;
            } else
            {
                count += parseInt(intermediate[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return count; 
}


console.log(sumDigits(2309));
console.log(sumDigits(-8525));
```